# Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

Tags: java

I try to move a lot of files from a authenticated directory to a server directory, but am getting this error

*Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /PGJ/portal/Importador_Documentos_Financeiro/FILES/FINANCEIRO/RF255677.pdf
    at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.(SmbFile.java:446)
    at importador_documentos.Main.main(Main.java:82)*

I tried a lot of things, but nothing has solved this, please can someone help me?

```
public class Main {
    public static String Pasta_Financeiro = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
            File.separatorChar + "FILES" + File.separatorChar +
            "FINANCEIRO" + File.separatorChar;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException,
            FileNotFoundException,
            IOException,
            AuthenticationException
    {
        try{
            jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("cabanellos.local", "deivisson.sedrez", "password");
            String path = "smb://fsct/scanpr$/";
            SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path.toString(), auth);        
            SmbFile[] varTeste = sFile.listFiles();
            SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(path.toString(), auth);
            System.out.println(dir.getDate());
            URL site;
            for(int i=0;i<varTeste.length;i++){
                if(varTeste[i].isFile()){                                        
                    //site = new URL((Pasta_Financeiro + varTeste[i].getName()).toString()); 
                    SmbFile dest = new SmbFile ("//"+Pasta_Financeiro + varTeste[i].getName());
                    dir.copyTo(dest);
                }
            }    
//rest of content...
}
```

Comment: Did you even look at the preview as you wrote your question? http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
SmbFile dest = new SmbFile ("//"+Pasta_Financeiro + varTeste[i].getName());
```

to:

```
SmbFile dest = new SmbFile ("file:///"+Pasta_Financeiro + varTeste[i].getName());
```

see [wikipedia file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Comment: Great, that worked, now I only have one problem authenticating hehe